# this jar holds/will hold

Tags: modal-verbs

[The Oxford Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/will_3) gives the following definitions for "**will**":

**Definition 7)** used for stating what is generally true.

*a) Engines **won't** run without lubricants.*

What is the difference between sentence a) and sentence b) of mine? Is a) less confident than b)?

*b) Engines **don't** run without lubricants.*

**Definition 8)** used for stating what is true or possible in a particular case.

c) This jar **will** hold a kilo.

What is the difference between sentence c) and sentence d) of mine? Is c) less confident than d)?

d) This jar **holds** a kilo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're speaking about what is generally true, your alternatives a and b mean the same thing.

But in the examples c and d of the jar, you are talking about a particular jar, which may or may not have anything in it. 
 "This jar holds a kilo." may be a statement about its contents right now, or about its capacity.
"This jar will hold a kilo." is a statement about capacity.

Answer (score 0):

I think A and C refers to a permanent future situation or in what condition things will be in the future.
As for B and D, The present tense suggests these conditions were true in the past, are true now, and will continue to be true for a foreseeable future.